# How do I get window title bars to stop glitching?

Tags: compiz, graphics, intel-graphics

Ever since the upgrade to Maverick, I've noticed that window title bars (or at least the names listed in them) take forever to refresh. I sometimes see them cut in half horizontally. Also, the hover-over window names I get when I'm using the Compiz scale plugin are often messed up.

Any idea what I can do to solve this? I'm on a Compaq Presario CQ62 which uses Intel graphics.

Comment: That sounds like graphics driver issues.  You might want to search for and/or report a bug on Launchpad.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is no visible activity or information added to it for several months. I have flagged a moderator and am voting for it to be closed. If you feel that the question is not abandoned and that you still suffer from this issue please flag a moderator so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

From the compiz wiki:

Windows Don't Update

When using the intel or ati driver with AIGLX, you may notice that all your windows seem to be frozen even as you interact with them. Nothing in any window updates until you rotate the cube or otherwise switch viewports.

Adding the following line to the Device section of your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file should fix the problem:

```
Option "XAANoOffscreenPixmaps" "true"
```

I had the same problem, and this worked for me. You probably already have an xorg.conf.failsafe file; modify and save it as xorg.conf

Comment: There isn't an xorg.conf on my system. I had to manually add one using the instructions at http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8382188&postcount=4

This created an xorg.conf.new in my home directory. Editing it did not solve the problem. I think we may be working on two different problems though, since my windows update just fine; it's the title bar that's laggy. That, and the hover-over title when I'm using Compiz scale.